# What is the difference between Variable fonts and regular fonts

Tags: css, font-face, font-family, typeface

I was reading about variable fonts and I don't get the concept.

There are 5 registered axes wght, wdth, ital, slnt, opsz. Font weight already pre-existed and we use it daily in our css.

**So what is the difference here between a variable font and a regular font?**

Also, if I put a range of `font-weight: 100 500` and then use `font-weight: 600` in `<p>` elements, I don't see any difference.

The weight 600 continues to work even tho I have limited it to 500.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "sketch_3dregular";
  src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/57225/IBMPlexSansVar-Roman.woff2")
    format("woff2 supports variations"),
    url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/57225/IBMPlexSansVar-Roman.woff2")
    format("woff2-variations");
  font-weight: 100 500;
  font-stretch: 85% 100%;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "sketch_3dregular";
}

p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  word-spacing: 0.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The main difference between variable fonts and regular fonts is that variable fonts are a **single file**. That one file holds every weight. With regular fonts, however, every weight has its own file.

Also, variable fonts can be set to **any weight under the sun**. Seriously; while regular fonts are limited to weights like "light", "regular", and "bold", variable fonts can be set to arbitrary weights like `375` and `458`, all the way up to `1000`.

A big use for having variable weight is **animation**. You can actually animate the font's weight, making for cool effects. Check out [this](https://codepen.io/JuanFuentes/pen/rgXKGQ) CodePen for a great example.

Finally, variable fonts can have other variables besides weight. Check out https://v-fonts.com and you'll see fonts with variable width, slant, and more.

For more information, I'd recommend reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/Variable_Fonts_Guide) article from MDN.

Comment: You can have different font weights in a single file without variable fonts

Comment: Also i have heard that variable fonts optimize font size but when i limit the range to  font-weight: 100 500; the size remains the same. Also for some reason i can continue using the 600 value even tho im out of the range

Answer (score 1):

Fonts have glyph outline data. If you have regular fonts for "regular" and "bold", then each of those has separate outlines. But in a variable font, there is one set of outlines *plus additional "delta" data* in which the font designer describes how the outline can be varied in a design-variation space of one or more axes. The delta data provides a maximal change along an axis, and you end up with a continuum from the original outline to the maximal modification, and any variation along that continuum can be selected.

So, a variable font can be described as being a whole family of fonts in a single file, but it's even more than that since that family now includes every small, incremental change along whatever axes are supported --- so not just a family with "light", "regular" and "bold" but also a continuous range of possibilities in between.

Animation was mentioned as a possible use. But even more significant for Web developers are access to greater typographic palette and smaller/fewer files to download.

I recommend a recent presentation by Mandy Michael, [Very Responsive Typography with Variable Fonts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kl72S-eBiTk&list=PL37ZVnwpeshH-mmcnUNoM7LVyegK27Gm1&index=10&t=0s&fbclid=IwAR2dmZxcpm45CmJTOlXJ05DCE2nGX-sL_is2gfMmAAYW3ukREk5ISCzBD2A), and also an article she wrote on performance, [The performance benefits of Variable Fonts](https://uxdesign.cc/the-performance-benefits-of-variable-fonts-79af8c4ff56c).

If you want to understand the technical details about how the variable font format works, there's an overview chapter in the OpenType spec, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otvaroverview).

The [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/Variable_Fonts_Guide) is also excellent.

As for your specific question about declaring a range `font-weight: 100 500` and then using `font-weight: 600` but not seeing anything different, any value outside the declared range will be invalid, and the UA will use the closest valid value. So in your example, `font-weight: 600` should give the same result as `font-weight: 500`.

Comment: When im using 600 weight i get different result from 500 weight. Letters become bold black when 600 weight is applied