# Font weight isn't working with variable fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I downloaded the Inter font [from google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter) and then took the variable font file and uploaded it to [font squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) so that I could just embed the base64 directly into my CSS.

The problem is that the font weight is not accurate as compared to using the separate downloaded weights (400, 500, 600). I read [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60816723) that with variable fonts you can use any font weight under the sun.

Instead, it looks like the only font weights available are 500 and 600. 500 is the regular one and 600 is extremely bolded (and kind of ugly). Am I doing something wrong? Here is my CSS declaration for the inline font:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff2');
}
```

Then in my code I set the font family to `Inter` and try altering its `font-weight`, but it only lets my choose two values instead of what I assumed would be an infinite amount due to the fact it's a variable font.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/tnc4y0w5/

My end goal is to be able to embed the Inter font (with just the Western languages subset) into my CSS and have it basically look-wise to the external google fonts link.

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like codepen.

[Here](https://codepen.io/radoslav-valchev/pen/KKVbgoj) is a simple example with Manrope font. I have included it via `link` tag. @Ryan Peschel

Answer (score 9):

For variable fonts, you want to use the [`font-variation-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variation-settings) CSS property, not the `font-weight`.

Also the file you are using represents one of the static versions of this font, to use variable fonts from GoogleFonts you can [request a range of weights](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2#axis_ranges) by appending `:wght@min..max` to the stylesheet's URL:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200..900');
.t1 {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 200;
}

.t2 {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 400;
}

.t3 {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 500;
}

.t4 {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 200;
  animation: weight 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes weight {
  50% { font-variation-settings: 'wght' 900; }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <span class="t1">hellofg</span>
  <span class="t2">hellofg</span>
  <span class="t3">hellofg</span>
  <span class="t4">hellofg</span>
</main>
```

Comment: Yeah, I haven't had an issue getting multiple font weights working with linking to google's fonts, only when trying to embed the variable font as base64. Could you give an example of doing that with font-variation-settings? Because I tried that property as well and could not get it working.

Comment: Also, how do you know I'm using the a static representation of the font as base64? I uploaded the variable font file to fontsquirrel for processing, so shouldn't the data URI base64 representation be of the variable font?

Comment: @RyanPeschel using the font-weight you weren't using the variable-weight properties of the font, but just different static font-weight. [Here is an example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JOjQwNFJ3oPbjZ3d?open=lib%2Fscript.js) using the correct `Inter-VariableFont_slnt,wght.ttf` file as a data:// URL. And I know you weren't using that file because the file you have is only 15KB while the real one is 748KB. Regarding FontSquirrel's services, I don't know about it, and it's off-topic for SO.

Comment: I was using that file. FontSquirrel lets you select a subset of the character set for exporting. Because I only selected ASCII characters the file size was much smaller. I guess I need to ask a separate question on how to properly turn these files into base64 while retaining the variable weight encoding.

Comment: Well certainly their service also scrapes out the variable-wght info from the font. And except if you are the author of this service and looking for help on how to fix it, asking about this would be off topic for SO as it's not programming related.

Comment: font-weight: [number]' works fine if you set font-weight: range in @font-face at-rule.
here is example for local fonts https://codepen.io/n4ks/pen/vYXxboa

Comment: @n4ks Please double check you only have the variable-font version installed on your system and not the whole set with different font weights.

Comment: @gpoole's answer down below worked better `font-weight: 100 900;` didn't have to manually declare all the font-weight one by one cause mine was actually going from 100 to 900.

Comment: @maiakd Google probably did change their setup since this answer was posted. Good there is a more up to date answer (by the way, you can sort the answers by "trending", gpoole's answer is first). I'll have to double check when I get time if mine needs an update or at least a notice, so thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 7):

The information available online around this change is quite confusing. You can use `font-variation-settings` to set the font weight and that will work, but the actual problem here was just that the `@font-face` was missing a `font-weight` in the declaration:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  /* need to specify a range of weights that are covered by this font face declaration */
  font-weight: 100 900;
  src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff2');
}
```

If you set the `font-weight` in the declaration, you get what the original asker was expecting without needing to use the `font-variation-settings` property. For example, this will now work:

```
h1 {
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold; 
}
```

In Kaiido's answer they mentioned using the following import along-side `font-variation-settings`:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200..900');
```

That doesn't seem to be necessary; if you inspect the source for the imported CSS you can see that it includes `font-weight` settings for the `@font-faces`, so it should work fine with regular `font-weight`s.

There's some more information on this available on the [MDN font-weight page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#variable_fonts) and [the MDN variable fonts guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/Variable_Fonts_Guide#using_a_variable_font_font-face_changes).

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Inter';
font-weight: 600; //700, 800 or ...
src: url(font);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix it, but perhaps I'm doing something wrong? It still doesn't let me set the font-weight to whatever I want and have it reflected on the page.

Comment: Please add a description as to how this helps the OP

Comment: What this answer means is you can define multiple font-faces with different weights, e.g. create another font-face with the weight set to 700 and call it 'Inter Heavy' or something. Then in your CSS you use it with `font-family: 'Inter Heavy'` instead of `font-weight: 700` which won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Kaiido:
font squirrel's generator apparently **converts variable fonts to static/single-weight fonts.**
This also applies to other converters like transfonter.
If you need to convert font files – make sure your converter definitely supports variable fonts.

#### Subset google fonts via subset query

To circumvent this problem you could retrieve an subsetted `woff2` file via `&text` query parameter from google fonts like so:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200..900&text=helofg
```

(resulting in a subset containing only the glyphs "h, e, l, o, f, g")

**Test the returned `@font-face` output.**
Due to googles **user-agent detection**, you might get static rules in some browsers – even though they support variable fonts flawlessly (e.g. chromium/blink based Opera browser). Firefox or Chrome should work perfectly.

#### Base64 Data-URL conversion

Use a "neutral" Base64 encoder that's only encoding the binary file without any font-optimizations.
See this answer by @Ilyich [Converting and rendering web fonts to base64 - keep original look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867893/converting-and-rendering-web-fonts-to-base64-keep-original-look#59116157)

#### Working example

```css
body{
  font-size:5vw
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'InterBase64';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200 900;
  src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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);
}

/* format("woff2-variations") */


@font-face {
  font-family: 'InterSub';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200 900;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMq14D4FCBW97h6&skey=c491285d6722e4fa&v=v12) format('woff2');
}

.InterBase64{
  font-family: 'InterBase64';
  font-weight: 400;
}

.interSub{
  font-family: 'InterSub';
}

.t1 {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.t2 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.t3 {
  font-weight: 900;

}

.variableTest{
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:12px">Font-weight: <input type="range" id="fontWeight" value="100" min="100" max="900" step="50"></p>
  <p id="variableTest" style="font-weight:100" class="InterBase64 variableTest">hellofg</p>

  <div class="InterBase64">
    <span class="t1">hellofg</span>
    <span class="t2">hellofg</span>
    <span class="t3">hellofg</span>
  </div>

  <div class="interSub">
    <span class="t1">hellofg</span>
    <span class="t2">hellofg</span>
    <span class="t3">hellofg</span>
  </div>

  <script>
    fontWeight.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      variableTest.style.fontWeight = e.currentTarget.value;
    })
  </script>
```

The above excerpt shows a range slider that seamlessly interpolates the font-weight. If you see fine-grained transitions, you have applied the correct variable font format.

As suggested by [@gpoole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482767/font-weight-isnt-working-with-variable-fonts#73300312) add a font-weight range like `font-weight:200 900` to you `@font-face` rule for best compatibility.