# "Variable weight" version of a TTF font not working in browser

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, google-font-api

I need to import a font (specifically in TTF for my application), and I chose the "Variable weight" version from https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat page, button "Download family". This variable weight version is called "Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf".

Why doesn't the `font-weight` work here? There are only 2 weights: normal and bold, and not all the variable weight. Why?

Isn't it the purpose of a `*_VariableFont_wght.ttf` vesion to have variable weight?

```css
@font-face { font-family: Montserrat; src: url(Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf); }
* { font-family: Montserrat; }  /* for the snippet to work, we need a CDN link for this TTF file */
.w400 { font-weight: 400; }
.w500 { font-weight: 500; }
.w600 { font-weight: 600; }
.w700 { font-weight: 700; }
.w800 { font-weight: 800; }
```

```html
<div class="w400">weight 400</div>
<div class="w500">weight 500</div>
<div class="w600">weight 600</div>
<div class="w700">weight 700</div>
<div class="w800">weight 800</div>
```

From the font README:

> Montserrat is a variable font with this axis:   wght
>
> This means all the styles are contained in these files:
> Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was [asked two years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482767/font-weight-isnt-working-with-variable-fonts) and got the same sub-optimal answer that needed a second answer to get the W3C recommended solution.

The problem isn't that you need to use `font-variation-settings`, but rather that your `@font-face` rule didn't have a `font-weight` declaration.

You can use `font-variation-settings`, but note that that does not work well in regard to cascading. (For details and workaround, see https://pixelambacht.nl/2022/boiled-down-fixing-variable-font-inheritance/.)

For this reason, CSS specs advise *against* using `font-variation-settings` in any case where a specific property could be used.

> When possible, authors should generally use the other properties related to font variations (such as font-optical-sizing), and only use this property for special cases where its use is the only way of accessing a particular infrequently used font variation.
>
> For example, it is preferable to use font-weight: 700 rather than font-variation-settings: "wght" 700.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#font-variation-settings-def

The better solution is to add a font-weight declaration in the @font-face rule. With a variable font, you can specify two values to declare a range of weights.

HTML

```
<div class="w400">weight 400</div>
<div class="w500">weight 500</div>
<div class="w600">weight 600</div>
<div class="w700">weight 700</div>
<div class="w800">weight 800</div>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  /* declare weights giving two values to specify a range */
  font-weight: 400 800;
  src: url(Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf);
}

* {
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

.w400 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.w500 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.w600 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.w700 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.w800 {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

---

Addendum: It turns out the misunderstanding about needing to use font-variation-settings to access different weights in a variable font is widespread. The Web Almanac site just published its [biennial analysis of font usage on the Web](https://almanac.httparchive.org/en/2022/fonts#variable-fonts), and it turns out that 87% of usage of font-variation-settings is for the 'wght' axis. They observe,

> This somewhat surprised us, because there is no need to use the low-level font-variation-settings property to set a custom weight axis value. You can simply use the font-weight property with a custom value, for example, font-weight: 550 for a weight between 500 and 600...
>
> ... Similar results can be seen for the optical size, width, italic, and slant axes, which can be set using the high-level font-optical-sizing, font-stretch, and font-style properties. Using the higher level properties will make your CSS more readable and avoid accidentally disabling an axis—a common source of errors with the low-level property.

Comment: The CSS working group added a `font-weight: auto` and made `auto` the default. So now in all browsers, variable font weights should work without specifying the `font-weight:` range anymore for the `@font-face`. Compare: https://wpt.fyi/results/css/css-fonts?label=master&label=experimental&aligned&q=font-face-weight-auto

Answer (score 1):

Use [`font-variation-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variation-settings) instead of `font-weight`.

HTML:

```
<div class="w400">weight 400</div>
<div class="w500">weight 500</div>
<div class="w600">weight 600</div>
<div class="w700">weight 700</div>
<div class="w800">weight 800</div>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  src: url(Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf);
}

* {
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

.w400 {
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 400;
}

.w500 {
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 500;
}

.w600 {
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 600;
}

.w700 {
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 700;
}

.w800 {
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 800;
}
```

[image: It works]

Comment: Correct, note that if you want to use multiple settings on the same element you'll need to make specific rules as you cant have multiple instances of the same property. So, in order to have a weight setting to 700 AND a width to 200 you'll need the following rule set :
Correct, note that if you want to use multiple settings on the same element you'll need to make specific rules.

  font-variation-settings: "wght" 700, "wdth" 200;

Comment: This is _not_ the right approach. See the relevant CSS spec, https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#font-variation-settings-def: "When possible, authors should generally use the other properties related to font variations (such as font-optical-sizing), and only use this property for special cases where its use is the only way of accessing a particular infrequently used font variation.

"For example, it is preferable to use font-weight: 700 rather than font-variation-settings: "wght" 700."

Answer (score 1):

*Besides from adding `font-weight: 200 900;` declaration.*

*Besides from using `font-weight: 500` is working -- so not need to use `font-variation-settings: 'wght' 500`*

---

(In my case,) I **removed `tech('variations')`** then it worked.

(idk why)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Crimson Pro';
  /*src: url('../externalFilesNt/fonts/CrimsonPro-VariableFont_wght.ttf') format('truetype') tech('variations');*/
  /*, url('../externalFilesNt/fonts/CrimsonPro-VariableFont_wght.ttf') format('truetype-variations');*/
  src: url('../externalFilesNt/fonts/CrimsonPro-VariableFont_wght.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 200 900;
}
```