# How to Implement 590 Font Wight in CSS Same as Figma Design

Tags: html, css, fonts, figma

I am working on a project and the designer who designed the UI has used `510` and `590` font weights which are not available in CSS.
Is there any way to implement the same font weight in CSS? I want to have the same design as figma.

Here is the code figma produced but `font-weight` doesn't work in the real CSS.

```
color: var(--white, #FFF);
font-family: SF Pro;
font-size: 25px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 590;
line-height: normal;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight : `In earlier versions of the font-weight specification, the property accepts only keyword values and the numeric values 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, and 900; non-variable fonts can only really make use of these set values, although fine-grained values (e.g. 451) will be translated to one of these values for non-variable fonts using the Fallback weights system.
`

Comment: `CSS Fonts Level 4 extends the syntax to accept any number between 1 and 1000 and introduces `[Variable fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#variable_fonts)`, which can make use of this much finer-grained range of font weights.` About your font, see this: css-tricks.com/… (you need the font to be installed in order to see the examples) but the idea is the [font-variation-settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variation-settings) property

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font weight isn't working with variable fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482767/font-weight-isnt-working-with-variable-fonts)

Comment: @ATP the question how can I implement the font-weight 510 and 590 which is produced by figma. Because CSS has only 500 and 600 font-weight

Comment: replace `font-weight: 590;` with  
 `font-variation-settings: 'wght' 590;`

Comment: Thanks, Although, this question looks similar to another but because it is mentioned with figma and can be helpful for beginners, I think it shouldn't be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ATP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9977151/atp) for comments. I figured out how this can work in CSS.

You first need to make sure you have the font variations like `300,400,500,600` etc. Without variations, it will not work.

Then you need to add `font-variation-settings: 'wght' 590;` instead of `font-weight:590`

Here is a simple example

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200..900');

.font-500 {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 500;
}
.font-590 {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 590;
}
```

```html
<span class="font-500">Font 500 </span>
<span class="font-590">Font 590</span>
```